# how to get the variable attribute of different activities/fragments with same variable name?

Tags: java, android, variables, if-statement, static

But if I got different activities/fragments with same variable name like:

**FragmentA.java:**

```
    public static int cat_id = 1;

    ...


    public static int getCategory_ID() {

    return cat_id;

    }
```

**FragmentB.java:**

```
    public static int cat_id = 2;

    ...


    public static int getCategory_ID() {

    return cat_id;

    }
```

**Parser.java:**
...

**how to get the category_id of each fragments to set them in if statement like:**

```
    int k_id = -1;

    ...


    k_id = current.getInt(...);


    if (k_id == cat_id) {

    do ... 

    }
```

Comment: You should respect Java naming conventions for your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are static methods so you can use them by class name

```
FragmentB.getCategory_ID()

FragmentA.getCategory_ID()
```

Comment: I think you can use Factory design pattern for this issue, but you need to change the structure of code use instance method listed of static

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/factory-pattern.html Factory design pattern example

Answer (score 0):

You can get them using class name as:

```
if(k_id==FragmentA.getCategory_ID())
```

OR

```
if(k_id==FragmentB.getCategory_ID())
```

Comment: that's the problem because i got an if statement and the k_id should be the  cat_id ... 

cat_id = FragmentA.cat_id;
cat_id = FragmentB.cat_id;

so how can i overwrite this value of each fragment ...

Comment: you can do :if (k_id ==FragmentA.cat_id) or if(k_id==FragmentA.cat_id)

Comment: But you should use the method.. So I have modified my answer.. I overlooked the method in the beginning :)

Comment: my solution is now :

if (k_id == FragmentA.getCat_ID() || k_id == FragmentB.getCat_ID() || .... ) 

...  

your OR helps me :D